# How do I declare an object of a class using the name entered by the user in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object

After we define a class, for example Class Game, in the main function we can declare like this:

```
int main(){
    Game Mario; 
    Game GameXXX;
}
```

I wonder if I can declare the object using the user input name? What I mean is like this:

```
int main(){
    string objectName;
    cout<<"Enter a name for an object:\n";
    cin >> objectName;
}
```

How can we use that "objectName" as the name of the object?

```
Game objectName;
```

Comment: Instead use a runtime based alternative. Create a map of objects, with the key as the value the user entered. You cannot name a variable after something the user enters. A variable name is only a compile time reference to that object.

Comment: Ok, so now move to the next step: How on earth is your code going to use a variable named by the user? Sounds like you want the name to be data in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannae be done, Captain. Names are a convenience for the programmer that the compiler strips down to an offset or a raw memory address. At runtime those pretty names are all gone.

What you *can* do is

```
std::map<std::string, Game> games;
```

so you can

```
games[objectName].playgame();
```

to run (or create and run) the mapped `Game` instance.

```
games.at(objectName).playgame();
```

if you want the program to get upset if the user types in an unknown game.

[Documentation on `std::map`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)